# How are libraries added to the Arduino library manager?

Tags: arduino-ide, library

Who curates the list of libraries in the `Tools / Manage Libraries` menu, and what is the procedure for submitting code for consideration?

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Library-Manager-FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [submit a ticket](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues) to the Arduino GitHub page. If you want to do this in an automated fashion, you can use [this python program](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/Arduino_IDE_Issue_Maker). Make sure beforehand that your library fits the [Arduino library specification](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Library-Manager-FAQ).